# SerializationException: Not marked as serializable during conversion of System._COM object to byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I am working on a website which is being developed in Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET 4.
I am trying to programmatically extract an image from a word document. The approach I am using  is this:

1. Convert WordApp.InlineShapes[1] (System._COM Object) to a byte[]
2. Convert byte[] to an System.Drawing.Image object
3. Save the image

But I am getting following exception in step1 itself:

```
Type 'System.__ComObject' in Assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.
```

I googled for two days but unable to understand the problem and the workaround as I am quiet new to developement in ASP.NET

The line that I am executing is this:

```
byte[] shapeByteArray = ObjectToByteArray(wrdDoc.InlineShapes[1]);
```

The method ObjectToByteArray is as follows:

```
    private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Following line is throwing the SerializationException:

```
return ms.ToArray();
```

Can you guys please help me understand and solve this issue?

Comment: You can't serialize a COM object which is what `BinaryFormatter` is attempting to do.  Try using the clipboard like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937487/extract-image-from-word-file

Comment: @Zer0 : Thanks for your response. I checked the link you have given but I am finding no way to access clipboard. It seems to be possible in Windows Forms Application but not in ASP.NET website. I am working on an ASP.NET website. Any idea what could be done?

Comment: You would have to find a different way to serialize that object.  `BinaryFormatter` won't work here because it's not marked `Serializable`.  I'm not familiar with the object you're trying to serialize so I couldn't write up a custom serializer.