# Microsoft Word Interop - Compress all images in a document

Tags: .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to [Compress a Picture](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Reduce-the-file-size-of-a-picture-5ad8ca3d-f251-4d96-a9ae-3e7ee374c91e#bm3) in word using its automation libraries.
can't figure out how to do that.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application app = new Application();
        Document doc = app.Documents.Open(DOC_FILE_PATH);

        foreach(InlineShape ilPicture in doc.InlineShapes)
        {
            //ilPicture.{compress the picture}
        }
    }
```

By default, MSWord does in fact compress the images on a document.Save() but it compresses it to 220ppi while I want it to compress them to 150ppi or 96ppi.

Doing it **manually** is easily achievable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may already know how to compress an image. If you're just looking for a way to get the image from a document, see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937487/extract-image-from-word-file).

It is unfortunate that Word does not expose that particular application option.