# Storing math equations from .doc MS Word file & restoring them

Tags: c#, math, ms-word, .doc

I'm processing Microsoft Word files which contain math equations and images.
I need to get these `InlineShapes` objects and store them **as is** & then restore them when needed.

I know how to get `InlineShape` objects from file, the problem is how can I store them. Saving them as images is not an option!

Comment: have you thought about storing them in Resource file or in a Database.?

Comment: Could you please show some relevant code you are using so far. It will be easier to undersand your problem then.

Comment: Can you store the inlineshape objects in memory?

Comment: @DJKRAZE , I want to store them in database if it's possible

Comment: Chingi3 I added a different solution please see the example below

Comment: @DJKRAZE thanks again.look is there any other way to store inlineshape besides saving them as images??

Comment: is this for a winforms or webforms application..? you can store and upload the file as imagebytes also do you have a database setup with the proper DataType..? varBinaryMax would work in regards to setting up the database type

Comment: anyway the result is image,i meant can i store the 'InlineShape' object as object with all its properties in order to restore it when i need.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Page = System.Web.UI.Page;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;
public partial class ReadIMG : System.Web.UI.Page
{   
    private Application m_word;
    private int m_i;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        object FileName = Server.MapPath("~/LectureOrig/Word.docx");
        object readOnly = true;
        m_word = new Application();
        m_word.Documents.Open(ref FileName,
            ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing,ref missing,ref missing);
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= m_word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count; i++)
            {
                m_i = i;
               // CopyFromClipboardShape();
                Thread thread = new Thread(CopyFromClipbordInlineShape);
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            object save = false;
            m_word.Quit(ref save, ref missing, ref missing);
            m_word = null;
        }
    }
    protected void CopyFromClipbordInlineShape()
    {   
        InlineShape inlineShape = m_word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[m_i];
        inlineShape.Select();
        m_word.Selection.Copy();
        Computer computer = new Computer();
        //Image img = computer.Clipboard.GetImage();
        if (computer.Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject data = computer.Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            if (data.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                Image image = (Image)data.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap, true);                
                image.Save(Server.MapPath("~/ImagesGet/image.gif"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                image.Save(Server.MapPath("~/ImagesGet/image.jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            }
            else
            {
                LabelMessage.Text="The Data In Clipboard is not as image format";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LabelMessage.Text="The Clipboard was empty";
        }
    }
```

Code copy from [How To Exctract images from Doc (Word) file in C#?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1474743.aspx)

[Converting Images from Word Doc to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870267/converting-images-from-word-document-into-bitmap-object)

Comment: I thought saving the inline shapes as images was not an option?

Comment: @jJack you right it's not an option.@DJKRAZE thanks for code but i can handle storing inlineshapes as bitmap,and I need somehow store them as is.