# transfering images and shapes from word file to pictureBox control

Tags: c#, ms-word

Can I read images and shapes from a Word file and display them in picture box control in C# pragmatically?

Actually I have a Word file in which I have questions with multiple answer and some questions also contain images and shapes.

So what I want to do is to read the document in C# and show the images and shapes to display in `pictureBoxcontrol`. So is it possible in C# and if it is then what is the solution. I have searched a lot on Google but didn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your Word document like the code above.
What it basically does is, it takes every picture, graph, table.

```
foreach (NetOffice.WordApi.InlineShape s in docWord.InlineShapes)
{
      #region Set Shapes
      if (s.Type==NetOffice.WordApi.Enums.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture &&  s.AlternativeText.Contains("|"))
      {
             Clipboard.SetImage(s.Select());
      }
}
```

Now to set it into your PictureBoxControl:

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"\Program Files\PictureBoxControl\tinyemulator_content.jpg");
```

And from Clipboard:

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(Clipboard.GetImage());
```

Comment: visual studio is now giving the error "Argument type void is not assignable to parameter  type  'System.Drawing.Image'" on `Clipboard.SetImage(s.Select());` so how i resolved this error. plz help me as i have accepted your answer but now facing problem\

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done Word automation for a while and I never used this function, but you can try using [`Range.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.copy%28v=office.14%29.aspx) - you'll have to locate the various `Shape` objects and images, copy them and they try pasting them into your picture box.

Also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870267/converting-images-from-word-document-into-bitmap-object) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937487/extract-image-from-word-file-c-sharp/7937590#7937590).

Answer (score 1):

You can create either a macro in your word document or in your c# code.
I don't know how to "simulate" a vba macro from your c# code but I know that you'll find lots of solution on stackoverflow. The code you need is something like.

```
activeDocument.Shapes(x).select
```

or

```
activeDocument.InlineShapes(x).select
```

you have to check if your image is an inlineshape or shape. Then copy it with

```
Selection.copy
```

That's the vba code.
the image is now in your clipboard so you need following c# code to retrieve it.

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
   Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
}
```